# Gradient in UITableViewCell Appearing Over Content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I am trying to add a gradient to the background of a custom cell, and when I display the gradient using addSublayer it shows over the rest of the content, and when I use insertSublayer: atIndex: 0 it doesn't appear.  This cell is a custom cell, what should I do?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:        (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ScoreCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor], nil];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:1];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Create a subclass, and add the gradient to the `backgroundView`'s layer while initialising. Please get familiar with tableviews. Table view cells are reused.

Comment: If inserting at index 0 isn't working did you try 1 ??

Comment: I'm aware that they are reused, this is a simplified version of what I am trying to do.  I want this gradient to be applied only in one cell, the others will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the following code. Remember that sublayers are listed from back to front order:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score -1):

UITableViewCell has a default background color of White. Set it to clear and you should be able to insert your gradient at index 0 and have it display.

Comment: Bad idea, performance-wise. Better to place the gradient at the right position in the layer hierarchy.

Comment: If I shouldn't make it clear, and atIndex:0 displays above all the text and 1 doesn't appear, what else should I do?

Comment: `UIView *tableBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[tableBackgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:tableBackgroundView];`          Are there benefits to using this?